# msvc flags: /MP /Zi /OD effect

Tags: visual-studio, qt, gcc, mingw, qt-creator

I am compiling a qt project in which in its .pro file there are these 2 lines:

```
       QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MP    
       QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /Od /Zi
```

I know that they are msvc flag and now I'm trying to compile the project using mingw on qt-creator..

So, I'm asking whether to safely omit them or there are alternatives for them in mingw ?

Comment: /MP has no equivalent, /Od for a release build is a terrible idea and should be avoided.  So yes, just omit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [scopes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qmake-language.html#scopes-and-conditions) to support compiler specific options in one project file:

```
win32-msvc* {
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MP    
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /Zi
}
```